# Using Biber in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

(This must be a duplicate, but I cant find this asked anywhere so...)

I am trying to make a bibliography in a LaTeX document. Currently I am successfully using a back-end of Bibtex in Biblatex. In the header I have

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}
```

in my document I cite using

```
\cite{bk:soulsby:1997:dynamics_sands} \cite{ppr:pyle:1989:tephra_fall}
```

and at the end I output

```
\printbibliography
```

The bib file is

```
@book{bk:soulsby:1997:dynamics_sands,
    author  ="Richard Soulsby",
    title   ="Dynamics of Marine Sands",
    year    ="1997"
    }

@article{ppr:pyle:1989:tephra_fall,
    author  ="David M Pyle",
    title   ="The thickness, volume and grainsize of tephra fall deposits",
    journal ="Bulletin of Volcanology",
    year    ="1989"
    }
```

I would like to use the biber backend, but changing the line in the preamble to

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric,citestyle=numeric]{biblatex}
```

results in all citations displaying [tag_name]. How do I fix this?

Comment: that's expected, then run biber (instead of bibtex) and run latex again and it should all work

Comment: Related: [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751)

Comment: how are you compiling?

Comment: Compiling using pdflatex in portable texstudio. Running multiple complies so I'm assuming that David Carlisles approach won't work? Wouldn't know how to do it anyway.

Comment: Try deleting the biber cache (see other posts which will tell you how to find it). Take a copy of the cache before deleting it as there is an unresolved question as to why this temporarily corrects a frustrating biber bug with the symptoms you have). I eventually suspended my use of biber until I get a chance to explore more. Interested to see what you get.